# SQL query - max and duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates, max

Im trying to find out how to use in this case MAX().
In result of this query I have duplicates and I want to find only one, latest record (here is date: CL.CL_DATE_FROM) and deduplicate it by db1.IDF and O.IDp.

```
SELECT
  db1.IDF as IDF,
  O.IDp as IDP,
  O.Action as Action,
  U.USR_IDENT as Operator,
  O.ID_T as ID_T,
  OC.OC_MEMO as MEMO,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CL.CL_DATE_FROM,120) as date,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CL.CL_DATE_FROM,108) as time
from OUTBOUND OC
  join CALL CL on CL.CL_ID= OC.OC_CL_ID
  join CAMPAIGN CA on CA.CA_ID = OC.OC_CA_ID
  join STATUSES ATT on ATT.AS_ID = OC.OC_AS_ID
  join USERS U on U.USR_ID = OC.OC_USR_ID
  join Outbound_Z O on O.ID = OC.OC_CUS_ID
  join db1.dbo.Clients db1 on db1.ID_T = O.ID_T
where CL.CL_DATE_FROM BETWEEN '2013-03-05 00:00:00.000' AND '2013-03-05 23:59:59.000'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `row_number()` for this:

```
with t as (
    SELECT db1.IDF as IDF, O.IDp as IDP, O.Action as Action, U.USR_IDENT as Operator,
           O.ID_T as ID_T, OC.OC_MEMO as MEMO, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CL.CL_DATE_FROM,120) as date,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CL.CL_DATE_FROM,108) as time,
           ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by db1.idf, o.idp order by cl.cl_date_from desc) as seqnum
    from OUTBOUND OC
      join CALL CL on CL.CL_ID= OC.OC_CL_ID
      join CAMPAIGN CA on CA.CA_ID = OC.OC_CA_ID
      join STATUSES ATT on ATT.AS_ID = OC.OC_AS_ID
      join USERS U on U.USR_ID = OC.OC_USR_ID
      join Outbound_Z O on O.ID = OC.OC_CUS_ID
      join db1.dbo.Clients db1 on db1.ID_T = O.ID_T
    where CL.CL_DATE_FROM BETWEEN '2013-03-05 00:00:00.000' AND '2013-03-05 23:59:59.000'
   )
select *
from t
where seqnum = 1
```

`row_number()` is a window function that assigns a sequential number to groups of records.  In this case, the groups are defined by the two ids.  The ordering is so the most recent gets assigned 1.

By the way, duplicates in a query like this are probably caused by the joins.  Different joins are to multiple rows, and the result is a cartesian product for the values.  You might also investigate to find the cause of the duplicates and fix the problem there.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something similar to this which will return the `max(CL_DATE_FROM)` for each `CL_ID`:

```
SELECT
  db1.IDF as IDF,
  O.IDp as IDP,
  O.Action as Action,
  U.USR_IDENT as Operator,
  O.ID_T as ID_T,
  OC.OC_MEMO as MEMO,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CL.MaxDate,120) as date,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CL.MaxDate,108) as time
from OUTBOUND OC
join
(
    select max(CL_DATE_FROM) MaxDate,
        CL_ID
    from CALL
    where CL_DATE_FROM BETWEEN '2013-03-05 00:00:00.000' AND '2013-03-05 23:59:59.000'
    group by CL_ID
) CL 
    on CL.CL_ID= OC.OC_CL_ID
join CAMPAIGN CA 
    on CA.CA_ID = OC.OC_CA_ID
join STATUSES ATT 
    on ATT.AS_ID = OC.OC_AS_ID
join USERS U 
    on U.USR_ID = OC.OC_USR_ID
join Outbound_Z O 
    on O.ID = OC.OC_CUS_ID
join db1.dbo.Clients db1 
    on db1.ID_T = O.ID_T
```